# Как определить цвет фона рабочего стола Android, откуда запускается приложение?

Tags: android

В моем приложении нужно реализовать метод, который смог бы определить перед запуском, какого цвета (основного) фон/обои рабочего стола.
Не знаю, в какую сторону смотреть. Запросы в google не дали желаемый результат.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для начала нужно получить картинку а потом с ней что-то делать, поэтому для получения делаем так:

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)wallpaperDrawable).getBitmap();
```

дальше мы можем получить цвет который больше всего встречается в этой картинке:

```
Palette.generateAsync(bitmap, new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
        // обрабатываем цвета...
    }
});
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471236/finding-the-dominant-color-of-an-image-in-an-android-drawable) первоисточник для обработки цвета. Так же есть возможность получить цвета при помощи [встроенных](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getwallpapercolors) средств.